# Do I have to urldecode() a urlencoded URL from a GET variable?

Tags: php

If I receive a url-encoded URL in a GET variable, and read it from a PHP file, will it already be decoded from the script's perspective?

On my local machine, this works fine; the URL seems to already be decoded presumably by the server or that's just the HTTP protocol.

Doing:

```
echo '<a href="' . $_GET['link'] . '">link</a>';
```

without `urldecode($_GET['link'])` will output a valid ("decoded") link.

But is this solution easily migratable and reliable? Does it depend on the PHP version or the Apache version?

Comment: I don't believe it depends on the version of Apache or of PHP. The web server would decode it based on the CGI specification, which you can find here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875

Comment: I suppose *using* urldecode() for url-encoded values is always safe...

Comment: @MarcoS — It is not. The decoded data might include characters with special meaning in URLs.

Comment: You are right, didn't think about it... :-(

Comment: @DavidFaber — The webserver will not decode it. That is the responsibility of PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

> The GET variables are passed through urldecode().

They will already be decoded. You should not decode them again.

---

You should, on the other hand, encode them for HTML with `htmlspecialchars` as echoing URL input directly out into the page renders you vulnerable to XSS attacks.